# Data bind input to list element in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I would like each one of my list items to be editable via the `input`. Clicking on the list item fills in the input, but how do I then specify what item to update? I have the `$watch` working.

Any help is appreciated.

I have a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/mslpklTaStKEdo64FpZl?p=preview

Here is the code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyController">

    <ul ng-repeat="item in collection">
      <li ng-click="edit(item.name)">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>

    <input  name="myinput" ng-model="myinput"  />
</div>

</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.collection = [
      {name:'foo'},
      {name:'bar'},
      {name:'foobar'},
      {name:'barfoo'},
    ];

  $scope.edit = function(current_name) {

    $scope.myinput = current_name;

    console.log(current_name);

  }

  $scope.$watch('myinput', function(NewValue, OldValue) {
    console.log(NewValue);
  }, true);  

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `$index` to `edit()` as well, so you know which index of the array to update later:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.collection = [
      {name:'foo'},
      {name:'bar'},
      {name:'foobar'},
      {name:'barfoo'},
    ];

  $scope.edit = function(current_name, current_index) {
    $scope.myinput = current_name;
    $scope.myindex = current_index;
  }
  
  $scope.$watch('myinput', function(NewValue) {
    if($scope.myindex) {
      $scope.collection[$scope.myindex].name = NewValue;
    }
  })

})
```

```html
<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in collection">
      <li ng-click="edit(item.name, $index)">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  
    <input  name="myinput" ng-model="myinput"  />
  </div>

</div>
```

Passing the actual `item` if possible instead, as the other answers say, is preferred tho.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to do this

```
<li ng-click="edit(item)">{{item.name}}</li>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.edit = function(item) 
{
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
}
```

And finally back in your markup

```
<input  name="myinput" ng-model="selectedItem.name"  />
```

What that does is to switch the currently editable item to whatever you click on, and then when you click on it, whatever you type into the input will update that item.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing edit(item.name), pass item itself. Then angular will handle the rest for you, there is no need for $watch or $index

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="MyController">

   <ul ng-repeat="item in collection">
     <li ng-click="edit(item)">{{item.name}}</li>
   </ul>

   <input  name="myinput" ng-model="myinput.name"  />
  </div>

</body>


JS:

var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.collection = [
  {name:'foo'},
  {name:'bar'},
  {name:'foobar'},
  {name:'barfoo'},
];

 $scope.edit = function(current_item) {

  $scope.myinput = current_name;

  console.log(current_name);

}

})
```

Comment: You haven't updated the code correctly. You are still calling edit(item.name) which passes the name property not the item.